# why grep is not finding words starting with underscore

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have words like

```
MEdIa
media
MEDIA
mEdIa
_media_
_media
media_
ICP_MEDIA
```

in a file.
i am trying to grep the keyword media from the below command

```
grep -irwE "media|*_media"
```

But grep can find only

```
MEdIa
media
MEDIA
mEdIa
_media
```

Not able to find `_media_` , media_ ,ICP_MEDIA

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure someone with better regex foo can provide a nicer solution, but this works for me for a selected set of values (see below):

```
cat file.txt  | grep -iwE "media|.*[\b_]media[\b_]*"
_media_
media
ICP_MEDIA
```

Values:

```
_media_
media
ICP_MEDIA
XXX_media_YYY
NOTMEDIA
NOT_MEDIAXX
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: *Why is grep not finding all matches*

> **`-w, --word-regexp`**: Select  only  those  lines  containing matches **that form whole words**.  The test is that the matching substring must either be
> at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
> character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
> followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
> This option has no effect if `-x` is also specified.

So the entry `_media_` is not matched to `media` or `*media_` for the following reasons:

- `_media_` is not a whole word match with respect to `media` as it misses the underscores
- `_media_` is not a whole word match with respect to `*media_` as, in regular expressions, an asterisk at the beginning of a regex is just an asterisk and looses its special meaning. And since `*` is different from `_`, there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

I've tryed this on te example you give:

```
   cat find | grep 'media'
```

and the resoult was this:

```
media
_media_
_media
media_
```

P.S `find` is the name of the file i put your examples in.

Comment: Did `find` contains ICP_MEDIA ?

Comment: This will, however, also match things like "lookslikemediabutisnot" because it does not consider word boundaries. From the OPs question it looks like this is what he needs.

Comment: @Christian.K, Yes.
My grep command is 
```
ret=$(grep -irE "${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}" "\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b|${LIST[$A]}[-_.*>@^:.,~%&\(\)\{}]|\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b" \
                "$package/" |grep -v "$filters\|${excluded_dir[@]}" -c)
`
Here the LIST contains words in an array.
The main intention is. The grep command should find all the words of media. But grep should not find the words like multimedia, intermediate.
The grep command should find 
```
media
_media_
_media
media_
MEdIa
media
MEDIA
mEdIa
ICP_MEDIA
`

Comment: No, `-v` negates a match. You probably wanted to use `-i`, which ignores case. But the OP already uses that. Also, no need to invoke cat and grep twice to achieve this.

Comment: @Christian.K you got it right man, with `cat find | grep -i 'media'` you can get every sting which contains 'media'

Comment: grep -irE "${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}" "\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b|${LIST[$A]}[-_.*>@^:.,~%&\(\)\{}]|\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b" \
                "$package/" |grep -v "$filters\|${excluded_dir[@]}" -c)

The above command searches only 
`MEdia`
`media`
`MEDIA`
`mEdia`
`_media_`
`media_`
But it is not finding ICP_MEDIA

Comment: And '[-_.*>@^:.,~%&()\{}]' this particular pattern is restricting to search ICP_MEDIA. Not sure.

Comment: @SampathKumarEsikala dude, try command i wrote in last comment...